# Eclipse Gradle buildship import sub project compilation error

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I have project `xxxWeb` using project `xxxAPI`. Both projects are sub project of a parent project. Project `xxxAPI` uses a third-party library jar `jar1.jar`, which has a class `somepackage.ClassA`. Project xxxAPI itself also has identical `somepackage.ClassA` that project `xxxWeb` intends to use.

However, Eclipse load `somepackage.ClassA` from `jar1.jar` instead, resulting in compilation error because `jar1/somepackage/ClassA` doesn't have the necessary fields like in `xxxAPI/somepackage/ClassA`.

In xxxWeb project classpath, Eclipse place xxxAPI project to the very end, which probably why the compiler pick `jar1/somepackage/ClassA` instead of `xxxAPI/somepackage/ClassA`.

This is not a problem in IntelliJ however.

Is there a cure for this?

The build script work fine, so I this is a question on Gradle's Eclipse plugin, and how to manipulate the generated classpath?

Comment: You should format this into a more legible form. A picture might be a good idea, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of gradle as of version 2.14.1. A workaround is to utilize the hook given by Eclipse Gradle plugin to remove the duplicated classpath entries

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged { cp ->
                cp.entries = cp.entries.unique{a,b -> a.path <=> b.path}
            }
        }
    }
}
```